# React Native ScrollView does not scroll in landscape mode

Tags: react-native

I am using scrollView component to scroll component. It works in local build. But after creating apk file it doesn't work. what can i do.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {
        submit ?
          isPreview ?
            <Text>Preview Page</Text> : <Text style={styles.text}>Thank you!</Text>
          : <Questions />
      }
        <PoweredByPEX />
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

i have used View and scrollView component here. i can debug after APK build file. what can i do now. i have used flex layout here. is there any way to sort it out.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work": gives you an error message, blank screen, scroll bar doesn't appear, etc.?

Comment: It doesn't scroll. It's stack. When we change to landscape mode it doesn't scroll.